# Grails - a conditional mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

Currently I'm developing a webapp which uses Oracle as a database. I've already been informed that my webapp has to work also on Sybase ASE. My Oracle database uses sequences to generate IDs and I mapped my domain classes to use those sequences. As far I know Sybase ASE doesn't have sequences but identities. And here is my problem. What to do with code/configuration to work with Oracle and Sybase. Some "conditional mapping" of ID for each domain would do.

I just don't want to comment/uncomment lines in mappings every time when I'm building webapp for other database than already mapped. **Have anybody any idea what to do?**

There is another danger: another differences between Oracle and Sybase which have influence on mapping (I don't generate database structure using `dbCreate = "create"`) . At this point I don't see anything. **Any experiences?**

---

**EDIT:**
It turned out that it's not possible make one mapping for both databases. My Oracle structure uses quotes in column and table names. And quotes are not allowed in Sybase ASE. My (not nice and pretty) solution is changing (comment/uncomment) mapping when building webapp on some particular platform.

Btw I'm huge fan of Grails and this mapping thing seems to be a drawback. If I was using "pure" Hibernate I'd have two mappings in xml files and I'd change them depending on an underlying database. But Grails doesn't give me possibility to have two mappings.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if grails enable to you to configure coditional mapping for id generation but I think that maybe you don't need use neither sequences or identities, and use other hibernate id generator strategy: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html.

EDIT:

Reviewing the hibernate documentation I found that is possible use sequences or identites according to capacities of database, from http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id:

> All generators implement the interface
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator. This is a very simple interface.
>   Some applications can choose to provide their own specialized
>   implementations, however, Hibernate provides a range of built-in
>   implementations. The shortcut names for the built-in generators are as
>   follows:
>
> ...
>
> **native**:
>
> selects identity, sequence or hilo depending upon the capabilities of
>   the underlying database.

So you maybe will need a configuration like this:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator:'native'
}
```

Comment: It sounds nice! When I finish installing Sybase, I'll try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check if it worked. I believe it is but ... my Oracle id names are quoted (like "SomeTableID"). Sybse ASE doesn't allow for quotes in column/table names. And here is what I was afraid of. I can't have a one mapping for both databases.